# Android Toolbar with multiple view on extended status

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I am using an android toolbar, and I want to make the following view:
[image]

I have the toolbar, and the view set, but I don't know what, and how to trigger, and what, in order to create a simple animation, like a scroll down, and tho show the view, and to change the color.

Many thanks.

Comment: Probably using a spinner view which in turn uses a card view. Changing the color would be just setting the background color of the spinner view to an orange or something similar.

Comment: you can use popupwindow below toolbar. check it out: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html